# how do I distinguish in a simple way a number in an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, types

I am learning now how to make my program distinguish two types of input in one function... I know its possible but how can I actually do it ;-;
Heres abit of my code:

```
def alphanumeric_input_detection(base_input):
    if (type(base_input)==str):
        return (print("you've written it wrong you dumm dumm"))
    else:
        return(print("thats correct input"))

base_input=input("please write a number")

alphanumeric_input_detection(base_input)
```

Comment: for first I was like "Hey letters are string and numbers are just ints or floats" but becouse of this I've realised that every input is count as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isnumeric()` function. It returns True if a string object is numeric.

```
s = '1'
print(s.isnumeric())
[Output] = True
```